# SystemState in WP7.1 C#

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I'm trying to check if camera is present on device by SystemState.CameraPresent.
in this tutorial:

http://breathingtech.com/2011/working-with-camera-on-windows-mobile-applications-net-compact-framework/

is info that i must attach Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status.dll and Microsoft.WindowsMobile.dll
but i can't find them.

Also haven't got Microsoft.WindowsMobile in Project->addReference

Environment: .net4, visualstudio2010, wp7.1 sdk, C#
Question: what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**Windows Phone != Windows Mobile**

You don't have access to the same DLLs and APIs. Very little of what was working with Windows Mobile works the same way with the Windows Phone SDK.

Comment: Dennis, if one had a Win7Phone, would an older Mobile 6 app run on it? I'm guessing a Win7Phone device would be running ...CF4? If that were the case, I don't even know if the prerequisites like CF3 would even install. (Obviously, I do not have a Win7Phone device)

Comment: No, you would have to re-write the application. The WP7 app model is completely different compared to Windows Mobile.